# how to send id from view to controller in anchor tag in codeigniter in ajax success function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

hey guys i am trying to send a id from view to controller using anchor tag.but the value that it shows on the controller is just the name.let me show you my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#search_form').submit(function(e){    
e.preventDefault();
var formData = new FormData(this);
jQuery.ajax({
type:'POST',
url:'<?php echo base_url("user/search_friends"); ?>',    
data:formData,
dataType:'json',
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
success:function(data)
{      
console.log(data);
var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);            
var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);    
$id=json.id;
$.each(json, function (key, data) {       
var uname=data.uname;
var id=data.id;
alert(id);    
$('#search_result').append('<li class="list_style"><a href="<?php echo base_url('user/profile_friend/data.id') ?>">'+uname+'</a></li>');    
});
}
});
});
 </script>
```

Now what i am doing is searching a username and showing the results, the results shown are in anchor tag thus the data has a link on it i want to send the user to its profile page using the id but the id does not get passed to the controller can you tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Well you can't pass js var on already rendered HTML DOM to finished php script. You could do the other way around (passing PHP var to javascript). Anyway, you probably want something like this maybe `<a href="<?php echo base_url('user/profile_friend') ?>'+data.id+'">'+uname+'</a>`? also i don't know whether `base_url` returns `/` in the end, so might want to include that before `'+uname+'</a>`

Comment: if i try to send it like that my url becomes 'user/profile_friend4' which is not existing @AdamK.

Comment: yea i have added that to edit - you probably want to add slash before `'+uname+'</a>`

Comment: no i want to add slash before data.id @AdamK.

Comment: when i try to that it gives me this error "SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag a"

Comment: My bad, i have copied wrong part of code - you are right about the data.id

Comment: is there any other way i can pass the id ? @AdamK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error hope it help someone else who wants to send data like this.

Just add slash like below

```
$('#search_result').append('<li class="list_style"><a href="<?php echo base_url('user/profile_friend/') ?>' +'/' +data.id + '">'+uname+'</a></li>');
```

That will send the value to the controller method.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
$('#search_result').append('<li class="list_style"><a href="<?php echo base_url('user/profile_friend/data.id') ?>">'+uname+'</a></li>');
```

to

```
$('#search_result').append('<li class="list_style"><a href="<?php echo base_url('user/profile_friend/') ?>' + data.id + '">'+uname+'</a></li>');
```

Comment: the url is being shown like this " 'user/profile_friend4' "